# Show Font Awesome icon aligned right when hovering over href, with separate link when clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a series of hrefs with class value set to: `text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1`. These links are wrapped in a div with class value set to: `list-group`

```
<div class='list-group'>
    <a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 1</a>
    <a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 2</a>
    <a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 3</a>
    <a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 4</a>
</div>
```

When hovering over one of these links, I'd like to display a Font Awesome icon ('fas fa-brain') aligned to the right of the list item, with the idea that if you click on the icon, you will go to a different destination than if you click anywhere else in the list item.

I suspect this might not be possible with just a series of hrefs (since I assume it isn't possible to embed a href within a href) but I'm at a loss to how to restructure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you.

**UPDATE**

I just added  `list-style-type: none;` in `.list-group li` selector for remove bullet.

```css
 .list-group li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
 
 .fas.brain_icon{ 
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 7px; 
    display: none;
   }
             
.list-group li a.list-group-item:hover + .fas.brain_icon, .fas.brain_icon:hover{
    display: block;
  }
 .list-group .list-group-item-action:hover{
  z-index: 0;
 }
```

```html
<!-- font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfrOj+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
<ul class='list-group'>
    <li><a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 1</a> 
        <a href="" class="brain_icon fas fa-brain"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 2</a>
        <a href="" class="brain_icon fas fa-brain"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 3</a>
        <a href="" class="brain_icon fas fa-brain"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' class='text-xs list-group-item list-group-item-action p-1'>Text 4</a>
        <a href="" class="brain_icon fas fa-brain"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try to implement above, my <li>'s show the standard 'li' bullet / dot. Is there a way to stop this from displaying?

Comment: Thank you very, VERY much!! I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Glad to helped you!!